# Error While running Mule

Tags: mule, mule-studio

While Running the Mule, I am facing the below error:

**Timeout waiting for mule context to be completely started**

Please let me know the work around solution for this. The same integration is working fine i.e the query fetching is happening fine with other system having mule but the same is not working in my system. Please Suggest a way to overcome this.

Thanks in Advance...!

Answer (score 0):

Goutham ...Did you configured timeout in your flow? If it is configured ..
1. is it configured in Munit which we need to look into run and wait scope..
2. Or is this coming during the shutdown of mule ?
You can set a timeout value to enable the current flow to complete. However, there is no built in method or utility to check what messages are in flight. You can connect a profiler and see the active threads (or just a thread dump), this should provide you an overview of what’s happening at the JVM level.

To ensure all inflight messages are processed you can shutdown mule in two steps:

Stop the flow(s) manually (this will prevent new messages from coming)

Stop Mule

Alternatively, you can set shutdownTimeout to a milliseconds value for a flow; hwoever this is not a global value.

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/starting-and-stopping-mule-esb
http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.mule/mule-core/3.7.0/org/mule/transport/AbstractMessageDispatcher.java

The second link will provide you the internal implementation of Mule's AbstractMessageDispatcher .Hope this helps.

Thanks